# Radio Buttons Table AS Submission Form

Tags: php, jquery, radio-button

I created a table of radio buttons,user can choose only one radio each col.
I called each col in the same name. for example : I have 20 radios each line, so each col is b1,b2,b3,b4.....b20,the selection working but now i need to send the data to php page to process, now my question is : how i can know for example if I chose @ b4 col one radio, how i can know what line he is ( I have only 4 ).
[image: Example]

this is my code:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "<table border='1'   cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
                        /** THEAD **/
    echo "<thead ><tr><th>".$StationHeader."</th>
    <th>".$OnlineStationHeader."</th>";
    for($k=1;$k<=20;$k++)
        echo "<th>".$k."</th>";
    echo "</tr></thead>";
                         /** THEAD **/
                         /** TBODY **/
    echo "<tbody>";
    for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++)
      {
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
       if($row['isWork']==1)
        echo "<td bgcolor='green'>ON</td>";
       else
        echo "<td bgcolor='red'>OFF</td>";
        for($j=1;$j<=20;$j++)
            {
                if($row['b'.$i.''])
                    echo "<td><input type='radio' name='b".$j."' selected/></td>";
                else
                    echo "<td><input type='radio' name='b".$j."' /></td>";
            }

        echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</tbody>";
                      /** TBODY **/
    echo "</table>";
```

Each line is a station ( this represent the table in my database ), now I want to update my table in my database.

1.I need to change the way i name the buttons?
2.On submit how i can know what line the radio button is selected?

p.s ( I didnt insert form tags yet ).
Thanks.

**EDIT - Updated the code **

```
echo "<form name='bakara' action='updateBakara.php' method='post'>";



  echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='12'   cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
                        /** THEAD **/
    echo "<thead ><tr><th>".$StationHeader."</th>
    <th>".$OnlineStationHeader."</th>";
    for($k=1;$k<=20;$k++)
        echo "<th>".$k."</th>";
    echo "</tr></thead>";
    $j=1;

    while ($tableRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // Loops 4 times if there are 4 returned rows... etc
        echo "<tr>";
        $i=0;

    foreach ($tableRow as $key => $value) { // Loops 22 times because there are 22 columns
    if($i>1){
    if($value==1)
                    echo "<td><input type='radio' name=b".$i." value=".$j." checked/></td>";
                else
                    echo "<td><input type='radio' name=b".$i." value=".$j." /></td>";
        }
    else{
    if($i==1)
        if($value==1)
        echo "<td bgcolor='green'>ON</td>";
        else
        echo "<td bgcolor='red'>OFF</td>";
    else
        echo "<td>".$value."</td>";

        }
        $i=$i+1;

}

$j=$j+1;
echo "</tr>";
}

    echo "</tbody>";
                      /** TBODY **/
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<input type='submit' value=".$SendButton." onclick='this.form.submit():'>";
        echo "</form>";
```

when i submit this form, i get error of unknown index b1,b2,b3,b4 there is something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set values for your radio button in this pattern

```
name="b1" value="1"   |   name="b2" value="1"   |   ....
name="b1" value="2"   |   name="b2" value="2"   |   ....
name="b1" value="3"   |   name="b2" value="3"   |   ....
name="b1" value="4"   |   name="b2" value="4"   |   ....
```

now get your value in php

```
$b1_value = $_POST['b1'];
$b2_value = $_POST['b2'];
```

and update your db

Comment: where i need to put the form tags?

Comment: outside the table <form><table>...</table></form>

Comment: i edit the question again, i put the form tags as need and i get the error unknowen index b1, b2,....

Comment: your radio input field name is invalid, name='b".$i."'